# Displaying a data stream using Python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to implement a data stream displayer using tkinter. I have a program that calculates some data and I want to program to display the data in chunks in a window as they become available (AKA data stream).

Consider this primitive example:

I want to display msg1 and wait 12 secs (A totally artificial delay that represent the expected delay of my calculations, which is variable) before displaying msg2. What the program does is it waits for 12 seconds then display the two messages together.

```
from tkinter import *
import time
window = Tk()

msg1 = Label(window, text="Display Part 1")
msg1.pack()
time.sleep(12)

msg2 = Label(window, text="Display Part 2")
msg2.pack()

window.geometry("600x600")
window.mainloop()
```

Your input is much appreciated!

Comment: you will need to calculate it in separated thead.

Answer (score 0):

GUIs don't work like `input()` - `Label` doesn't create widget at once but it inform what widget to display and `mainloop` creates window and display it. So you `sleep` before it even creates window.

Other problem can be that `mainloop` has to run all time to get key/mouse event from system, send events to widgets and update/redraw widget in window. If you use `sleep` then it will stop `mainloop` and it will freeze window.

You can use `root.after(millisecond, function)` to execute function after delay.

```
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred
import time

# --- functions ---

def add_label():
    msg2 = tk.Label(window, text="Display Part 2")
    msg2.pack()

# --- main ---

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("600x600")

msg1 = tk.Label(window, text="Display Part 1")
msg1.pack()

window.after(12000, add_label) # 12000ms = 12s

window.mainloop()
```

---

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

---

**BTW:**

If you want to do some calculation at the same time then you will have to do it in separated thread. But you can't uses widgets in other thread so you may need to send text from other thread using  `queue` and main thread will need to use `after` to check periodically `queue` and add new text to GUI.

```
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred
import time

import threading
import queue
import datetime

import random

# --- functions ---

def calculations(q):
    while running:
        # some calculations
        time.sleep(random.randint(1, 10))
        # create message
        text = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        # send message using queue
        q.put(text)
        
def check_queue():
    # check if there is new message in queue
    if not q.empty():
        # get new message
        text = q.get()
        # append in `Text`
        textbox.insert('end', text + '\n') 

    # repeate after 0.1s
    window.after(100, check_queue) # 100ms = 0.1s
    
# --- main ---

running = True
q = queue.Queue()

t = threading.Thread(target=calculations, args=(q,))
t.start()

# - GUI -

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("600x600")

textbox = tk.Text(window, bg='gray')
textbox.pack()

button = tk.Button(window, text='Exit', command=window.destroy)
button.pack()

window.after(100, check_queue) # 100ms = 0.1s

window.mainloop()

# - end - 

running = False  # stop loop in thread
t.join()         # wait for the end of thread
```

Comment: "You can use root.after(millisecond, function) to execute function after delay."

Thanks for the answer. However, the delay is artificial, I was just using a delay in my example to substitute for the expected delay of my calculation, which will be variable.

So I don't want to set a constant delay there, I want to display the data as soon as it becomes available.

Comment: second version uses `calculations` to simulate delay (I could use `random` to simulate random delay) and it uses `queue` and `after` to get message with any delay. Using `0.1s` in `after` it may get message as soon as it is possible.

Comment: I added `random` in `calculations` so now you have example with random delays and it gets message as soon as it is possible.

Answer (score -1):

It is better to run time-consuming task in a thread so that it won't block tkinter `mainloop` from handling pending events and updates.

And the time-consuming task can notify the main task when it completes the task via tkinter *virtual event*.

Below is an example:

```py
from tkinter import *
import time
import threading

def calculation_task():
    print("started")
    # simulate calculation
    time.sleep(12)
    print("completed")
    # task completed, notify main task via virtual event
    window.event_generate("<<Complete>>", when="tail")

def on_complete(event):
    msg2 = Label(window, text="Display Part 2")
    msg2.pack()

window = Tk()
window.geometry("600x600")

msg1 = Label(window, text="Display Part 1")
msg1.pack()

# bind virtal event
window.bind("<<Complete>>", on_complete)
# start calculation task in other thread
threading.Thread(target=calculation_task).start()

window.mainloop()
```